# Controller won't connect to PS4 after connecting to phone

Tags: ps4

I recently had to get a new hard drive for my PS4, and during the process I had connected my controller through Bluetooth to my phone, and I can't download the system software update because my controller won't connect to the PS4. The controller only stays on when I connect it to my phone, and I do not have the money to get a new controller, so I need another alternative. I have even tried restarting the controller.

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se]! We're happy that you solved your problem, but please post your solution, so that other users with the same problem can benefit from it.

Comment: I'm going to guess they used the cable to connect the controller to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Plug the controller into the PS4 while they are both off. Then power on the PS4 and wait until it says "Push the PlayStation Button" on the screen while the controller is still connected to the PS4. Turn on the controller and it should work.